# How can I keep my dwarf from walking to his doom?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

*Goden Geshudenam has died after colliding with an obstacle.*

I discovered the hard way that dwarves will walk, to their doom, across a partially deconstructed bridge. Sadly one of my masons is in the process of removing a bridge. And another dwarf, pictured below, is walking towards his untimely demise.

How can I stop him?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Recruit him into your militia.
2. Activate your milita.
3. Station him somewhere, anywhere, else.
4. Wait for the bridge to finish deconstruction.
5. Discharge him from the militia.

Comment: Your dwarf will get unhappy for drafting him especially if he has no combat skills.

Comment: @MennoGouw actually, he will only get unhappy if he has no combat skills, and the mood hit is so minor it is barely worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on why your dwarf is moving there and if there are other ways of moving there. You could open up a (temporary) shorter and saver route so the dwarf will be taking this route.

Otherwise with "d"+"o" you can assign traffic areas. Basically each tile has a movement cost of 2. The path finding algorithm considers movement cost. So if you mark certain areas to have a movement cost of 25 your dwarfs are less likely to consider these tiles, unless of course there are no other routes or the path of 25 move cost tiles would be still faster. If you have a hallway with a length of 10 tiles and make them all cost 25 points dwarfs will detour 125 default tiles since 10 * 25 = 250 / 2 = 125.

With this method you can also make a temporary floor next to the bridge and mark the bridge tiles with 25 movement cost so they take the floor next to it.

Comment: Pretty sure dwarves won't dynamically update their routes unless their current route is blocked, so neither creating a shorter route nor using traffic zones to make that route less appealing will work on a dwarf that is already on his way to destruction.

Comment: Yes, but games like this are about planning ahead. I know the question is about "how to stop him" but a valid answer (imho) would be to never get to that point.

Comment: In that case you should make it more clear that this is a preventive measure, not a solution to an ongoing situation.